# Remove duplicate data leaving only the most recent record - Postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora

I have a question where I have a table in my postgres db where it has several columns, but I need to check two columns and delete only the oldest record

Example:

| id_insert | id_store | id_client | XXX | ZZZ | YYY | inserted_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | 3222 | 3331 | aaaa | ddsdad | dsdaad | 2022-11-28 19:53:34.898 |
| 56 | 3222 | 3331 | aaaa | rarsad | dsadaw | 2022-11-29 23:33:16.593 |

in the case of the table above, I need to create a query that deletes the line "23" where the id_store and id_client are the same, but I need to make the date inserted_at newer

I tried to use a query that I used in sql server, but it is not working in postgres

```
with cte as (select id, cliente_id,max(inserted_at) max_data
                        from public.tray_orders
                        group by id, cliente_id)
                        delete t
                        from public.tray_orders t
                        inner join cte
                        on  (t.id = cte.id)
                        and (t.inserted_at <> cte.max_data)
```

Error:

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "t"
  Position: 193
```

Comment: You want `DELETE FROM …`, not `DELETE t FROM …`. And you'll have to use [`USING cte WHERE …` syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-delete.html), not a join.

Comment: I tried this, and it gave me the following error:  SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "inner"
  Position: 269

Comment: As I said, do not use a `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE temp TABLE tray_orders (
    id_insert bigint,
    id_store bigint,
    id_client bigint,
    XXX text,
    ZZZ text,
    YYY text,
    inserted_at timestamptz
);

INSERT INTO tray_orders
    VALUES (23, 3222, 3331, 'aaaa', 'ddsdad', 'dsdaad', '2022-11-28 19:53:34.898'),
    (56, 3222, 3331, 'aaaa', 'rarsad', 'dsadaw', '2022-11-29 23:33:16.593');
```

delete record that `id_insert` = 23

```
 BEGIN;
    WITH cte AS (
        SELECT
            id_store,
            id_client,
            max(inserted_at) AS max_data
        FROM
            tray_orders
        GROUP BY
            1,
            2)
    DELETE FROM tray_orders t USING cte
    WHERE t.id_store = cte.id_store
        AND t.inserted_at <> max_data
    RETURNING
        *;
    
    TABLE tray_orders;
    
    ROLLBACK;
```

manual(https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-delete.html):

```
DELETE FROM [ ONLY ] table_name [ * ] [ [ AS ] alias ]
    [ USING from_item [, ...] ]
```

So you can not use

```
delete t from public.tray_orders t
```